# Keras: Why isn't model.fit() returning the same values as model.evaluate()?

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, keras

In another question the asker had a batch normalization layer, but there isn't one present in this case.

```
model.fit(training_data, training_targets, batch_size=16, epochs=1)
```

> Epoch 1/1 33350/33350 [==============================] - 18s - loss:
>   0.0926 - acc: 0.9703         Out[708]:

```
model.evaluate(training_data, training_targets)
```

> 33248/33350 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s   Out[709]:
>   >[0.027722493904928553, 0.99157421289355319]

```
model = Sequential([
    LocallyConnected2D(10, kernel_size=(20, 20), strides=4, padding='valid', activation='relu', input_shape=(50, 110, 1))
    , Dropout(0.3), Flatten(), Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
])

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics='accuracy'])
```

Comment: Are u suing dropout/batch_norm in your model?

Comment: Yeo, as you can see in the model, there is dropout.  Dropout affects it as well?  Hm.. then how are we supposed to trust the accuracy of the model.fit?

Comment: fit uses the training graph for accuracy calculation, so dropout is used. But evaluation doesn't use dropout. That's the reason behind the changes in accuracy. Using a validation data with evaluation graph help deciding the model generalization.

Comment: I see! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The loss you see in the progress bar is the per-batch loss, not evaluated in the full training set. When you use `model.evaluate` you are evaluating over the full training set, so as expected the losses are not the same.

Also as people mentioned in the comments, Dropout is disabled during evaluation at test time so it also affects the results.